# Counter argument to overwrite a DLL

Tags: windows, dll

We want to hot reload a DLL. The first idea was to overwrite the .dll file then reload it from the application. However the file is write protected.

Is there a (documented) counter-argument to not remove this file protection and overwrite the file? 
If no such counter-argument exist how do we bypass this protection?

EDIT: References found on internet point out mmap and the fact that the DLL may not have been loaded. In my case, the (only exported) method has been called so I can reasonably think that the DLL has been fully loaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I load a dll in such a way that it can be deleted while it's loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546912/can-i-load-a-dll-in-such-a-way-that-it-can-be-deleted-while-its-loaded)

Comment: "I can reasonably think that the DLL has been fully loaded." But isn't that the opposite of what you want? You want to reload the DLL, but replacing the file would have no effect since it's already been fully loaded. (Of course, the real problem is when the memory gets paged out and needs to get paged back in. Also, the imported functions would now be pointing to the wrong place.)

Comment: You're just doing this a bit too hot, you must use FreeLibrary() first.  Since you have to rebind the exports anyway there is little reason to make it any hotter than that.  Consider ReadDirectoryChangesW() to detect an update getting dropped in an anointed place.

Comment: @Raymond, the DLL has been used by the application for a while but a new version has been compiled and should replace the currently running behavior.

Comment: @HansPassant, it's actually a good answer except my problem is a bit more complicated. The dll is being built while the application is running and by another application. So we cannot Free it yet. The solution I'm exploring so far is to rename the file first (it seems I can do it from a third application while the first one is still accessing it).

Comment: There is more to it, you are likely to have some fun battles with anti-malware trying to stop you when you do this.  Good luck.

Comment: @FloFu The host application needs to rebind its imports to point to wherever the function is in the new DLL. Since you already have to change the host application to get it to do rebinding, you may as well change it to use FreeLibrary/LoadLibrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our situation we have a program that loaded and use a DLL.
An edit in the source code of this DLL is made, we need to recompile it and have it hot-reloaded by the program. The problem is the DLL is locked against write.

We have another program that watch for any modification on the source file (this is actually a custom script Compiler) and need to compile a DLL (by translating the source script into c++ code and invoking clang).

The solution we have for some month now (and is working pretty well), is to have our Script Compiler to check if the file is protected against write, if so it rename this dll with a temporary name and finally compile.

The Main program catch the change on this dll and is able to reload it.

Extra step At the startup of the compiler, we check if there is any temp dll and try to removed them. If the deletion fails it's probably because the DLL is in use, we ignore it.

Note: We need to move the .dll and .pdb to a temporary file. We delete the .exp, .ilk, and .lib just in case of.